# How to display vowels in a word or alternative text if none are present

Tags: python

```
list = ["amita","aman","ishita","rythm"]
k = 0
for str in list:
    print (str)
    for ch in str:
        if(ch=='a' or ch=='e' or ch=='i' or ch=='o' or ch=='u'):
            print(ch)
        else:
            print("there is not any vowel in the word")
```

I want to display the vowel of every word. If there are not any vowel in the word it should just display `"there is not any vowel into the word"` one time. But the above code is displaying `"there is not any vowel into the word"` for the last name in the list `"rhythm"` multiple times instead.

Comment: If you want to check there is no vowel in the word, you need to go through the _whole_ loop looking for vowels, and then print "there is not any vowel" _after_ the loop if you didn't find any.

Comment: This depends on whether or not you consider `"y"` a vowel. If you do, you can fix your code easily. If you don't, your code is correct.

Comment: If one character isn't a vowel you immediately conclude that the whole word doesn't have any vowel inside?

Comment: @mad_ that would not work for what is required

Comment: add a flag set to `False` outside the inner loop (inside the first) and set it to `True` when you see a vowel. At the end print "no vowel" if it's still `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag, try this too

```
list = ["amita","aman","ishita","rythm"]
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']# you can add y

for str in list:
    print(str)
    contains_vowel = False
    for ch in str:
        if ch in vowels:
            print(ch)
            contains_vowel = True
    if not contains_vowel:
        print("there is not any vowel in the word")
```

Answer (score 4):

This approach using set intersections will print each unique vowel in each word:

```
names = ["amita","aman","ishita","rythm"]
vowels = set("aeiouy")

for name in names:
    print(name)
    intersect = set.intersection(set(name), vowels)
    if intersect:
        print("\n".join(intersect))
    else:
        print("there are no vowels in the word")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
list = ["amita","aman","ishita","rythm"]
for str in list:
    print (str)
    vowel_count = 0
    for ch in str:
        if ch in vowels:
            print(ch)
            vowel_count += 1
    if vowel_count == 0:
        print("there is not any vowel in the word")
```